# Rescaling images based off parent image in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to add responsive images to my webpage. The problem is that I have several overlapping images which then don’t get rescaled correctly.

[Diagram Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cICDV.png)

Not sure if I’ve set something up wrong, am missing something or trying to over-reach beyond what bootstrap can do.

This is the test code I’m using, I’ve kept it generic.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-12" >
  <!-- Images inside the container image that are not being rescaled -->
  <div class="children_Images">
    <img class="img-responsive" id="image_1" src="insideImage_1.png" alt="" style="left: 0.6em; top: -0.5em"/> 
    <img class="img-responsive" id="image_2" src="insideImage_2.png" alt="" style="left: 0.6em; top: -0.5em"/>
    <img class="img-responsive" id="image_3" src="insideImage_3.png" alt="" style="left: 0.6em; top: -0.5em"/> 
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: relative; /* Allows children to be placed relative to the panel */
  font-size: 10px;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container img{
  max-width:100%;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  border:5px solid green;
}

.children_Images
{
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
}

.children_Images:hover
{
  transform: scale(1.05) translate(4em);
}
```

I’m just wondering if this is possible with CSS and Bootstrap or should I be doing something with JavaScript that rescales all the children images once the parent image’s size has been altered?

Comment: Post code here, not an image

Comment: Sorry, wasn't sure which one to use. Changed it now

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img src="" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img src="" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img src="" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And css

```
.container img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```